# Is this reallocation method correct

Tags: c, realloc

My code works but my question is if this dynamic allocation is correct. It's works well and all is ok but I'm not so sure it is correct.

```
        StudentDynamic* pStudents = NULL;
        char auxfirstName[255], auxlastName[255];
        float auxGrade;
        FILE* pFile = fopen("InitialDB.txt", "r");
        if (pFile == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open file or is empty! Exiting...");
            exit(2);
        }
        int i = 0;
        pStudents = (StudentDynamic*)malloc(sizeof(StudentDynamic) * 1);
        while (!feof(pFile))
        {
            fscanf(pFile, "%s", auxfirstName);
            pStudents[i].firstName = (char*)malloc(strlen(auxfirstName) + 1);
            strcpy(pStudents[i].firstName, auxfirstName);

            fscanf(pFile, "%s", auxlastName);
            pStudents[i].lastName = (char*)malloc(strlen(auxlastName) + 1);
            strcpy(pStudents[i].lastName, auxlastName);

            fscanf(pFile, "%f", &auxGrade);
            pStudents[i].grade = auxGrade;

            i++;
            pStudents = (StudentDynamic*)realloc(pStudents, sizeof(StudentDynamic) * (i + 1));
        }
        nStudents = i;
        fclose(pFile);
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: [Please see Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Comment: why not using `strdup` instead of malloc+strcpy?

Comment: if it's correct maybe corereview would be a better place to get comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, i will read but my misunderstanding is if it's correct the part with declaring char auxfirstName[255], auxlastName[255]; and then do the dynamic allocation.

Comment: I'm still wondering if casting mallocs is really as bad as some of you say. I know "old-school" C programmers that prefer to keep the cast. I am really a newby and this confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp_pStudents  = realloc(pStudents , sizeof(StudentDynamic) * (i + 1));
if (!temp_pStudents)
    // error
pStudents  = temp_pStudents ;
```

Ideally this would be something like this. Otherwise in case of error you have a memory leak. Also this saves you from derefrencing the null pointer.

Again other things include

- casting `malloc` which is not necessary.
- And using constructs with `while(!feof(file))`. Don't use it. Check the discussion posted in comment.

Comment: temp_pStudents how should be declared?

Comment: @Bogdy.: `StudentDynamic *temp_pStudents `.

Comment: Now I get crash.. Could you check if you want, please? https://pastebin.com/kFGLRN54

Comment: @Bogdy.: Your code has undefined behavior. `fflush(stdin)` etc...Make changes to it or ask proper question or even better get a book.